# Passing data from child to parent, with an init in the child

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass data from my child view to the parent view. I also pass some data from the parent to the child.

```swift
struct Parent: View {
...
    var body: some View {
        OneColumnList(changeStage: changeStage, icons: icons, options: options)
        ...
```

```swift
struct Child: View {
    var changeStage: (Int) -> ()
    var icons: [String]
    var options: [String]
    
    init(icons: [String], options: [String]) {
        self.icons = icons
        self.options = options
    }
...
```

I currently get this error on the child:

```bash
Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

I guess I need to initialise `changeStage`, but I can't work out how to do it. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to enhance your init method of the `Child`.
E.g.

```
 init(changeState: @escaping (Int) -> (), icons: [String], options: [String]) {
        self.changeState = changeState
        self.icons = icons
        self.options = options
    }
```

Then you can handle the state changes in your `Parent`, like for example

```
Child(changeState: { myInt in print(myInt) }, icons: icons, options: options)
```

Comment: Thanks @Meritum, this worked, but for the Child call in the Parent I can simply do ``changeStage: changeStage``

Answer (score 0):

*changeState* according to its type should be a completion block, that receives one Int argument and returns Void. Try adding this to the init:

```
self.changeState = { someNumber in }
```